# Set --net=host in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

How can I avoid passing `--net=host` to my `docker run` command and define it inside a Dockerfile like below? I find lots of examples for `network_mode` in compose but not Dockerfile?

```
FROM alpine
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

Comment: it is not possible.

Comment: (You shouldn't need host networking in most cases; if the program in your container requires host networking to be functional, consider whether it might be more straightforward to run it directly on the host without the Docker isolation layer.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I use openvpn and it can't reach anything but 8.8.8.8 without passing this. I don't 100% understand why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not define network mode in Dockerfile. According to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image.

So only you can create a image with Dockerfile. If you want to set network mode you should use in `docker run` or compose file.